# Separating closed sets by clopen sets in $\omega_1$.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I'm trying to verify that given two disjoint closed subsets of $\omega_1$ there is a clopen set $C$ containing one and disjoint from the other. I'm not seeing it at the moment, thanks for any help.

Comment: Does $\omega_1$ has any other property? Because if it is only topological space then you have no chance to seperate them with clopen set. For example in $\mathbb{R}$ the only clopen sets are $\mathbb{R}, \emptyset$.

Comment: @dem0nakos I think he is refering to the order topology induced by the well ordering of $\omega_1$. That is not $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

Comment: Oh okay , thats why i asked ! thanks

Comment: If two closed sets are both unbounded, they intersect. So the hypothesis only occurs when one of the closed sets is bounded above.

Comment: Used your hint and completed the details a bit to give an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S,R\subseteq\omega_1$ be disjoint closed sets.
As any pair of closed unbounded subsets of $\omega_1$ intersect, either $R$ or $S$ must be bounded, and hence compact.
Assume $S$ is compact.
For every $\alpha\in S$ we may fix, using the fact that $\omega_1$ has a basis of clopen sets, a clopen neighborhood $U_\alpha$ of $\alpha$ that does not intersect $R$.
Let $\{U_{\alpha_i}\}_{i≤n}$ be a finite cover of $S$ consisting of these neighborhoods.
Then, $\mathcal{U}=\bigcup_{i≤n} U_{\alpha_i}$ is the closed-and-open set we were looking for.